# List of properties to anonymous Type

Tags: c#, function, lambda, anonymous-function

Say I have some type:

```
public class General
{
     public int Id;
     public string Name;
     public DateTime modified
}
```

Say I want some function filter to Anonymous:

```
public void DoWorkOnSubset(List<General> generals, params Func<general, object> properties)
{

}
```

How could I take the list of properties and convert it into an anonymous type

```
generals.Select(x => new { properties.ForEach( p => p.Invoke(x)) });
```

Comment: So basically copy the type? What are you trying to achieve with this?

Comment: Anonymous types are expanded to a concrete implementation at compile-time.

Comment: Basically I want a subset of the type as an anonymous but I don't know until the properties are passed in

Comment: @Scorpion are you saying that I won't be able to use an anonymous type because, It has to be established at compile time?

Comment: There is no easy way to do this, you would have to build the new type dynamically. It can be done, but it is not easy. Use reflection to get the properties of the existing type and use `TypeBuilder` to build types dynamically. Either way I question what you hope to accomplish here, you will get an object you can only use through reflection.

Comment: What good is the anonymous type if you don't know the properties at compile time?  How do you expect to code anything against it?

Comment: I tend to forget expression trees because the only time I use reflection is to inspect things. Granted, I have created a proxy class for some services to implement logging, but that code is long buried.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen I've deleted my comment as it was about creating instances with expression tree (as you can't create whole type with it - misunderstood the question).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot produce a new anonymous type at run-time, because anonymous types are actual types, produced by the compiler behind the scene. The code to produce these types is not available to users of .NET through the API, so you would have to go through [`System.Reflection.Emit`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.emit.typebuilder(v=vs.110).aspx) calls to build your own.

The next closest thing would be using a dynamic object, such as the [`ExpandoObject`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dynamic.expandoobject(v=vs.110).aspx), and set its values using the `IDictionary<string,object>` interface. The callers would be able to access fields of this object using the regular syntax.

**EDIT :** If all you need is a collection of property values in a way that you can access at run-time, you could use `Dictionary<string,object>`, like this:

```
generals.Select(x =>
    properties.ToDictionary(p => p.Name, p => p.Invoke(x))
);
```

Comment: You can in fact build types at runtime, look at [TypeBuilder](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.emit.typebuilder(v=vs.110).aspx) though they will be of little use since no code can use the properties directly. You can implement interfaces on the new type though, that would make it easier but that would probably run counter to the generic method the OP asks for.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen Ah, of course, you can build your own classes if you go through emit. It would be an exercise in coding a building block of a simple compiler, though.

Answer (score 1):

In case anyone was wondering I figured out a way to achieve this with out an anonymous type.  I just have an IEnumerable of properties instead.

```
generals.Select(x => properties.Select(p => p.Invoke(x)));
```

I can operate on this as an IEnumerable instead of an anonymous type

Comment: Better yet, you could run a `ToDictionary`, and operate on it as a dictionary (see the edit to my answer for the code). The issue with `IEnumerable<object>` is that it could get really slow due to deferred execution, unless you convert it to list.

Comment: Thanks for the tip I'll probably switch to dictionary because then it will be easier to know what I'm working with based on key

Answer (score 1):

I had same solution and solve that by a simple class and inheritance all my entities from it:

```
public class Entity
{
    public Entity()
    {
        EntityPropertyDic = new Dictionary<string, object>();
    }
    public object this[string propertyName]
    {
        get
        {
            if (EntityPropertyDic.ContainsKey(propertyName))
            {
                return EntityPropertyDic[propertyName];
            }
            else
                throw new ArgumentException("PropertyName Is not exist!");
        }
        set
        {
            OnColumnChanging(propertyName, ref value);
            EntityPropertyDic[propertyName] = value;
        }
    }

    private void OnColumnChanging(string propertyName, ref object value)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    protected Dictionary<string, object> EntityPropertyDic { get; set; }
}
```

so you can do like this :

```
public List<Entity> DoWorkOnSubset(List<General> generals, params string properties)
{
    List<Entity> entityList = new List<Entity>();
    foreach(var general in generals)
    {
        var entity = new Entity();
        foreach(var prop in properties)
        {
           entity[prop] = general[prop];
        }
        entityList.Add(entity);
    }

    return entityList;
}
```